# AD Connect when removing user from syncing OU

Tags: entra-id

Trying to utilise AD Connect as the preferred sync tool and still learning...

I have created a separate OU and installed a custom ADC install to sync all users in this OU.. All worked fine but to continue with finding out about  how ADC  works I decided to remove the user account from the OU and into another OU, thinking that the account would just be de-synced. Obviously that is not the case as the account in 365 is placed into the deleted users group on 365.. Not a problem as just restored this user in 365 and that is now back to a AAD user and no link to the on premises AD.

When I try and put the user back in the syncing OU and run the sync PS command to force syncing the user never goes back to being a Windows Server AD source..

How can I get this user account to resync after removing from the syncing OU and the putting it back in there?

Answer (score 0):

You can softlink or hardlink the user again.
Softlink is with UPN, if both users have the same UPN, it should match again. Make sure that the Office 365 user isn't changed to .onmicrosoft.com address.

If that's not the case, try to delete the immutable id attribute in Office 365.

```
Set-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName <user> -ImmutableID "$null"
```

If that's not working either, make sure the immutableid is the same as the guid of the onprem ad user. Than it will hard match, no matter what.
[Check this source how to do it.](https://blog.ahasayen.com/azure-ad-guid-azure-ad-immutableid-converter/)